# Is it possibly to make a box plot from these data outside of a data frame, using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How would I go about using these vectors in ggplot2 functions, for example to create a scatter graph or box plot? I think I need to implement them in to a data frame, if so how would I go about that?

```
> am_C <- c(56.44898,62.85714,53.91837,64.65306,74.28571,69.40816,60.79592,54.07576,59.87879,56.90909,69.39394,72.90909,77.36364,62.30303,59,54.46429,60.4,63.63571,70.82143,71.3,61.07143,74.62222,66.24444,67.46667,66.41481,67.7037,77.69259,64.81111)
> am_O <- c(65.26923,69.11111,70.88235,65.36364,65.75,66.8,72.72727,70.15385,69.58,70.71667,72.8,65.28571,65.875,77.4,72.64706,67.83333)
```

Comment: BTW, am_C has 28 values and am_O has 16. Are they meant to correspond to one another? If not, a scatter plot would seem inappropriate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned by @JonSpring, a scatter plot is inappropriate based on the length difference between your two vector, so let's try a boxplot:

**Boxplot (using plot)**

First, you can go fast by doing:

```r
boxplot(am_C, am_O, names = c("am_C","am_O"))
```

[image]

**Boxplot (using ggplot2)**

Alternatively, you can make beautiful and highly personalized boxplot by using the library `ggplot2`. However, you need to re-arrange your data in order to fit the `ggplot2` grammar. Briefly, you should have two columns, one for labels and one for values.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(Value = c(am_C, am_O),
                 Variable = c(rep("am_C",length(am_C)),rep("am_O",length(am_O))))

ggplot(data =df, aes(x = Variable, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

At first, `ggplot2` is not really easy to use but one you will get in it, you won't be able to do without. Here, just few example of possible customization:

```r
# fill with color
ggplot(data =df, aes(x = Variable, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_boxplot()

# customize color filling:
ggplot(data =df, aes(x = Variable, y = Value, fill = Variable)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "orange"))

# add individual point on top of it:
ggplot(data =df, aes(x = Variable, y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would point out that your vectors are not the same length so, if one is x and one is y you have a bunch that cannot be plotted.

If you make them the same length it becomes fairly simple.

```
 library(ggplot2)
am_C <- c(56.44898,62.85714,53.91837,64.65306,74.28571,69.40816,60.79592,54.07576,59.87879,56.90909,69.39394,72.90909,77.36364,62.30303,0,0)
am_O <- c(65.26923,69.11111,70.88235,65.36364,65.75,66.8,72.72727,70.15385,69.58,70.71667,72.8,65.28571,65.875,77.4,72.64706,67.83333)
ggplot(data.frame(am_C,am_O),aes(x=am_C, y=am_O)) + geom_point()
```

If those are not meant to be X and Y I will need some clairification.